# MVC How to handel submit button on dynamically added partialview

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I have just started MVC Programming, so pls excuse my noob question.

I have a Index View with dropdown. And According to the dropdown value, I have added a partial view '_create' in ContentDiv of Index using jquery.

```
$('#CreateButton').click(function (e) {
    $("#ContentDiv").load('/Controller/_Create?Id=' + $("#DropDownList1").val());
});
```

So, now I am not sure how to handel submit button inside that partialview (_Create)

My _create form looks like:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("_Create","controller", FormMethod.Post,
        new { id = "addFormData", name="addFormData" }))
    {
    ----------
    ----------
     <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
        </p>
}
```

Controller:

```
 [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
            public ActionResult _Create(WorkFieldModel entity, FormCollection p_form)
            {
                addFormValuetoDB();
                return PartialView();
            }
```

And One more thing; how to maintain viewstate of dynamically added partial view after postback.

Any Help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an AJAX request to submit the form to avoid performing a full postback to the server and loosing the context:

```
$('#CreateButton').click(function (e) {
    var data = { id: $("#DropDownList1").val() };
    $("#ContentDiv").load('/Controller/_Create', data, function() {
        $('#addFormData').submit(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(result) {
                    alert('Thanks for submitting the form');
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

Since your `HttpPost` controller action returns a PartialView you could use this information in the `success` callback of the form submit and inject the result somewhere in the DOM.